# Getting Ionic v4+ infinite scroll working without showing scrollbars

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, infinite-scroll, ionic5

Has anyone worked out how to get infinite scroll working while also hiding scrollbars?

This is the scss I use to hide scrollbars:

```
ion-content {
    --padding-bottom: 200px!important;
     --offset-bottom: auto!important;
    --overflow: hidden;
     overflow: auto;
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

This is the html part:

```
...
    <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="10px" (ionInfinite)="loadData($event)">
        <ion-infinite-scroll-content
          loadingSpinner="lines"
          loadingText="Loading more data...">
        </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
      </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

and this is the .ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonInfiniteScroll , IonContent,ModalController} from '@ionic/angular';
...
export class GlobalRankingsPage implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(IonInfiniteScroll) infiniteScroll: IonInfiniteScroll;
  @ViewChild(IonContent) content: IonContent;
...
loadData(event) {
    if(this.nextPage!=null){
      setTimeout(() => {

      this.globalRank(); //this just adds records to the dataList
      event.target.complete();
      if (this.dataList.length >= 150) {
        event.target.disabled = true;
      }
    
      }, 300);
    }else{
      event.target.disabled = true;
      event.target.complete();
    }
  }
 
  toggleInfiniteScroll() {
    this.infiniteScroll.disabled = !this.infiniteScroll.disabled;
  }
...
```

If I remove the css (so scrollbars show) the infinite scroll works fine. But if I hide the scrollbars the loadData function doesn’t get triggered.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this thread offers some assistance?  https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/hide-scrollbar-but-still-be-able-to-scroll/107146/10

Comment: That thread (ignoring the insults) provides an answer on how to hide scrollbars generally in ionic. However, doing so then prevents the infinite scroll from triggering for some reason above my pay grade. I currently have a choice: implement this solution and loose infinite scroll, or have infinite scroll but also show scrollbars. I want infinite scroll and hidden scrollbars.

Comment: But the insults are the best part :-D

Comment: Did you find any solution? @IanM

Comment: @juanjotorres Not for desktop - I noticed when testing the app on mobile devices that my original code does not show them.

Comment: Try this workaround: [link](https://codepen.io/liamdebeasi/pen/QWbEbpO) It's working great for me on ionic 5!

Answer (score 1):

Try this workaround in AfterViewInit:

```
const main = async () => {
  const content = document.querySelector('ion-content');
  const styles = document.createElement('style');
  
  styles.textContent = `
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 20px;
    }

    /* Track */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

    /* Handle */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background: red; 
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

    /* Handle on hover */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
      background: #b30000; 
    }
  `;
  content.shadowRoot.appendChild(styles);
};

setTimeout(() => {
  main();
}, 250);
```

You can style the scroll bar or just simply hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating width of the scrollbar

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
     background: transparent;
     display: none;
     width: 0;
}
```